# Как разграничить доступ к данным на уровне базы данных?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

в базе данных созданы три роли: guest,customer и admin.
В самом проекте также реализованы три варианта подключения к базе данных:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'guest',
        'PASSWORD': 'guest',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    },
    'admin': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    },
    'customer': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'customer',
        'PASSWORD': 'customer',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Как и где я могу менять подключение к БД в зависимости от того авторизован пользователь или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, тут вы неправильно используете термин "авторизован". Вы имеете ввиду "аутентифицирован".

Это можно сделать используя несколько ингридиентов:

1. middleware - для определения, какую БД использовать в зависимости от того, аутенифицирован пользователь или нет. Это нужно, чтоб этот механизм работал при обработке веб запроса.
2. threadlocal - для хранения текущей выбранной БД
3. [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers), который будет выбирать БД, которую нужно использовать

```
request_db = threading.local()


class DbRouterMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.user.username == 'admin'
                db_name = 'admin'
            else:
                db_name = 'customer' 
        else:
            db_name = 'default'
        request_db.name = db_name
        return None

    def process_response( self, request, response ):
        if hasattr(request_db, 'name'):
            del request_db.name
        return response


# django использует этот класс, чтоб определить к какой БД обращаться
# Мы тут используем значение из request_db, если оно есть, иначе 'default'
# А значение в request_db положила DbRouterMiddleware 
class DatabaseRouter(object):
    def _get_request_db(self ):
        return getattr(request_db, 'name', 'default'):

    def db_for_read( self, model, **hints ):
        return self._get_request_db()

    def db_for_write( self, model, **hints ):
        return self._get_request_db()
```

Нужно сконфигурировать middleware и router в django settings:

```
# DbRouterMiddleware использует результат работы
# SessionMiddleware и AuthenticationMiddleware так что порядок важен
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    ...
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "path.to.my.DbRouterMiddleware" 
]

...
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [DatabaseRouter]
```